# Add UIViews to UIStackView programmatically inside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistackview, reuseidentifier

I have three elements `UILabel`, `UIImageView` and `UIButton` in a list. I have to show them accordingly inside `UITableView`. I have an array like this:

```
tableArray = [["label", "img", "button"],["img","button","label"],["img","label","button"],["button", "img", "label"]]
```

The positions of the elements are same as the positions of them (index) inside the array. My `cellForRowAt` looks like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? FirstTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let tableData = tableArray[indexPath.row]

    var count = 0
    tableData.forEach { (element) in
        switch element {
        case "label":
            let lbl = self.createLabel()

            cell.stackView.insertArrangedSubview(lbl, at: count)
            count += 1
            break
        case "img":
            let img = self.createImage()
            cell.stackView.insertArrangedSubview(img, at: count)
            count += 1
            break
        case "button":
            let btn = self.createButton()
            cell.stackView.insertArrangedSubview(btn, at: count)
            count += 1
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

**The problem is whenever I am scrolling `TableView` every time those items are added into the cells.**

I have tried few solutions to solve that but no luck.

1. `if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) == nil` then add elements into stackviews.
2. Checking `if cell == nil` after `dequeueReusableCell`.  If nil then `init` the cell.
3. `let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil) as? FirstTableViewCell` tried even without `dequeueReusableCell`.

But the same thing happens every time.

This is the `FirstTableViewCell`

```
class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Any idea how to check if elements are already added to `StackView`, then I'll not add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the cells are reused, the first thing you need to do in `cellForRowAt` is "reset" your cell... in other words, clear out the existing subviews from the stack view:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? FirstTableViewCell else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    // remove the views that are currently in the stack
    cell.stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach {
        $0.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // the rest of your setup
    let tableData = tableArray[indexPath.row]

    var count = 0
    tableData.forEach { (element) in
    ...
}
```

Now, based on the code you presented, if the cells always contain a `UILabel`, `UIImageView` and `UIButton`, just in different orders and with different properties, you could add them once when you create the cell (or add them in your cell prototype if you're using one), and then simply re-arrange them as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer. It worked like a charm.